# php pregmatch_all url with specific word between double quotes

Tags: php, regex

I am having a very  hard time coming up  with a regex that works in this situation. 
I am trying to use pregmatch_all to capture the url between quotes which contain "720.mp4" resulting in the url without the double quotes.

```
[{"file":"https:\/\/cw012.videohost.com\/files\/videos\/2017\/09\/18\/1505738417e8b76-720.mp4?h=33wg3l1i1G0XcJxvT82x7Q&ttl=1505769928",
```

In the end i want the above to result as

```
https:\/\/cw012.videohost.com\/files\/videos\/2017\/09\/18\/1505738417e8b76-720.mp4?h=33wg3l1i1G0XcJxvT82x7Q&ttl=1505769928
```

Any ideas ? I am very new to regex, i have done my reading but cant put what i have read to work with this specific case.

Comment: That's an incomplete JSON string.  Get the whole string and use `json_decode()`.

Comment: Try to edit your code and reformating your scope to be more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple approach you can use:

```
preg_match_all('#"([^"]*720\.mp4[^"]*)"#', $str, $m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```

The steps are straightforward. We want a literal `"`. Then we open a capture group (`(`), then anything that is not a `"`, then the literal string `720.mp4` (with an escaped dot, because `.` has a special meaning). Again anything but `"`, close the group, and a final `"`.

`$m[1]` is the content of the capture group we want. `$m[0]` contains the entire match with the quotes.

Comment: Great. Please accept my answer, unless you think it's incomplete.